# Continuous monitoring Azure DevOps Release

Tags: azure-devops, azure-application-insights, azure-monitoring, azure-web-app-for-containers, azure-monitor

I am trying to create a setup where I deploy a "Webapp for containers" but I want to build in some checks via Azure Monitor. My idea is to deploy the webapp and then have a gate that checks an azure monitor alert set with availability. When the availability check fails then it should rollback.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/continuous-monitoring) states **"When the release pipeline detects an Application Insights alert, the pipeline can gate or roll back the deployment until the alert is resolved"**, but I don't know how to configure this in azure devops.

I have an AppService Plan and a web app running. I also created an Application Insights instance and I enabled continuous monitoring through the *"Azure App Service manage"* task.
The alert I created is:

```
az monitor metrics alert create -n 'Availability' -g ${RG_NAME} --scopes "${APP_INSIGHTS_PROD}" \
--condition 'avg availabilityResults/availabilityPercentage < 90' \
--description "created from Azure DevOps"
```

As Post Deployment-Condition I enabled the Gates and I configured it to check for the Availability alert, which works. When I adjust something to make the app fail on purpose the Gate works and fails the Stage eventually.
I also enabled the auto-redeploy to deploy the last successful deployment but that does not do anything because the actual deployment task was successfully finished.. just the gate failing and failing the stage.

Comment: I cannot find an option to configure custom conditions on stage level via the UI. If I want to do it via azure pipelines (yaml) then I don't have the option to configure gates via yaml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I build the Release via the UI, to make it work I had to create the pipeline via yaml. With deployment jobs I could use environments and in the Azure DevOps UI you can configure the environment to add a check. Query Azure Monitor Alerts is one of the available checks to add for an environment.
The check is done at the beginning of a job so I created a separate deployment job that refers to the environment with the Query Azure Monitor Alert check.
After that I created another job that has a dependson and condition which will only run if the query alert job failed. And that job will swap slots.

Comment: Great! Thanks for sharing your solution here, you could accept it as the answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.